# Two almost identical project in VS2017. One has working nuget references the other doe not?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I have two almost identical project files in VS2017

https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/318b0241a46eeab81a8546bc1c28c1f8
[image: The diff between the two files]

However **dotliquidextensions** project seems to load the nuget packages

[image]

But the other does not.

[image]

The original differences were much greater but I have reduced them to being almost identical. I cannot figure out what might be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I've noticed something stranger. "Weingartner.Safenet" package is not mentioned in my cutdown csproj files. But it still shows in visual studio even after a restart.

Comment: You could try re-running a NuGet restore. The NuGet package dependencies used are stored in the obj/project.assets.json file.

Comment: No. Did nothing __MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.__

Comment: But pressing F6 _Rebuild_ does make both reference lists the same. But now there are no nuget packages listed and there is no obj/project.assets.json file for either project.

Comment: I was using the wrong version of nuget to force the restore. Now am using v15 and the project.assest.json file is regenerated with all the nuget packages included. But!! The but the nuget assemblies  still do not show up in the solution.